# Visual Studio 2017 Choose Tabs Docked to bottom

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 17 has a handy new feature where some tabs are docked at the bottom and only appear when you click on them. I accidentally deleted the error list from this list and can't find the option to restore or dock other tabs. How do you do this?

N.B this is different from simply dragging and dropping an open tab to the bottom to pin it in place, I'm talking specifically about adding items to the bottom menu items shown in my screenshots. Thanks!

[image: closed showing tab list at the bottom]

[image: open once clicked]

Comment: Those are not menu items. They are docked windows that have collapsed. The thumb tack (pin) icon in the window title controls that behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the correction re what they are, but either way using the thumb tack does not move these windows to the list at the bottom. Do you know how I do that?

Comment: As you drag the window, drop it on the "dock to bottom" icon.

Comment: Thanks Sam - it's what you suggested in combination with using the autohide. If you add an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are not menu items. They are docked windows that have collapsed. The thumb tack (pin) icon in the window title controls that behavior.

As you drag the window, drop it on the "dock to bottom" icon